# EMF files panose font objects can't be created

Tags: fonts, gdi, wmf, .emf

I'm looking over the EMF file spec and the LogFontPanose object never seems to be used.

**EMF Specification:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-emf/91c257d7-c39d-4a36-9b1f-63e3f73d30ca

There are a few types of font objects that are avaialabe: LogFont, LogFontEx, LogFontExDv, and LogFontPanose.

In section `2.3.7.8` they give the algorithm for determining which type of font object is created by the `ExtCreateFontIndirectW` record by examining the size of the `elw` field.

> If the size of the elw field is **equal to** or less than the size of a LogFontPanose object (section 2.2.16), elw MUST be treated as a fixed-length LogFont object. **Bytes beyond the extent of the LogFont object, up to the end of the elw field, MUST be ignored**.
>
> If the size of the elw field is greater than the size of a LogFontPanose object, then elw MUST be treated as a variable-length LogFontExDv object.

Going by this algorithm, a logFontPanose object can never created.  If the elw is a LogFontPanose length, it has to be a LogFont object with the all the bytes from the panose object being ignored. Is this a mistake in their spec?

Comment: I'd guess probably not. It sounds like something that might have been tentatively considered in very early Windows or OS/2, but GDI does not have a LOGFONTPANOSE structure. (See GDI [Font and Text Structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/font-and-text-structures)

Comment: I'm not sure, if I got the implementation right, but [this](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/poi-scratchpad/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/hemf/record/emf/HemfFont.java) is the way I've parsed it.

Comment: @PeterConstable: Did you Ctrl+F "Panose" in your link?

Comment: @kiwiwings Yes, I searched in that page. Moreover, I searched through the Windows source code (I work at Microsoft): there is a PANOSE structure, but there is no LOGFONTPANOSE.